# How to check if user has already done voting in C#

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, ado.net

I am making a simple voting system, that when a voter is already done voting and tries to re-log in, the system will read the database and stop the voter from logging in. How can I do that?

What I have in my database :

username, password and remarks. remarks is when a voter is "Done" or "Not Voted".

What I have in my code now :

```
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader dr;
string cmdall = "Select from Voter where username=@user and password=@pass and remarks=''"; //got no clue as to what i am going to command here..

using (cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdall, _db._conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", _user);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", _pass);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    /* Then if and else statement */
}
```

Please help me out, im kinda new at this.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: why don't you use a bit field?

Comment: it lookd like He has basic knowledge but he is not able to make logic how to check if  user already voted

Comment: Don't use a `Remarks` column to store if the user has voted. Instead either use a `bit` column as suggest by daniel or create another table `VotingStatus` with (now) two records `ID=1,Status='Voted; ID=2,Status='Not Voted;'`. Then store the appropriate `VotingStatusID` as column in `Voting` and use `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Voting WHERE username=@user and password=@pass and VotingStatusID=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As HasVoted`. You can use `(int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()` to retrieve the single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You query should be like:

```
string cmdall = "Select remarks from Voter where username=@user and password=@pass";
```

and then check it's value is  **Done** :

```
while(dr.Read())
{
  if (dr["remarks"].ToString() == "Done")
    // already voted

}
```

as @Daniel pointed in comments better would be to use `bit` in database because it's suitable in your case , there is only two chances `true` or `false`